# Whats wrong in this SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY mysql syntax?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Returns a syntax error, but I dont understand where is the mistake... 
NOTE: dtadd is a TIMESTAMP

```
SELECT codigo, quantidade, preco_unitario
FROM romaneios_detalhes 
WHERE id_romaneio = '.$idr.' 
SORT BY dtadd ASC
```

Answer (score 7):

It should be `ORDER BY` not `SORT BY`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ORDER BY` instead of `SORT BY`

Answer (score 3):

First, that should be `ORDER BY`

Secondly, the points around $idr .. are they just an artefact from copying them out of a PHP script?

Comment: Nops, it's de ID of a list of products in my table... it's come from a a $_GET... that I assign to $idr

Comment: so your IDs actually look like this:  `.123.`?